# Home folders created in powershell won't work: Access Denied

Tags: windows, powershell, active-directory

I'm having some trouble creating home folders with powershell, I create the folder

```
New-Item -Path "C:\Homes\" -name $username -ItemType Directory
```

Then I copy the ACL and disable the inheritance and add the new permissions

```
$Rights = [System.Security.AccessControl.FileSystemRights]"FullControl"

$Inheritance = [System.Security.AccessControl.InheritanceFlags]::"ContainerInherit", "ObjectInherit"  

$Propagation = [System.Security.AccessControl.PropagationFlags]::None

$AC =[System.Security.AccessControl.AccessControlType]::Allow

$NewACL = New-Object System.Security.AccessControl.FileSystemAccessRule ($username, $Rights, $Inheritance, $Propagation, $AC)

$ACL = Get-Acl -Path "C:\Homes\$username"
$ACL.SetAccessRuleProtection($True, $False)

$ACL.SetAccessRule($NewACL)

$NewACL = New-Object System.Security.AccessControl.FileSystemAccessRule ("SYSTEM", $Rights, $Inheritance, $Propagation, $AC)
$ACL.SetAccessRule($NewACL)

$NewACL = New-Object System.Security.AccessControl.FileSystemAccessRule ("Administrators", $Rights, $Inheritance, $Propagation, $AC)
$ACL.SetAccessRule($NewACL)

Set-Acl -Path "C:\Homes\$username" -AclObject $ACL
```

Finally I mount the folders as H: and set it as home dir

```
Set-ADUser -Identity $username -Replace @{HomeDirectory=$homeDir}
Set-ADUser -Identity $username -Replace @{HomeDrive=$homeDrive}
```

When I login to a user and try to add a file/folder I recieve permission denied.
The Root Folder (C:\Homes) is shared and has configured permissions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Louis J. Are you sure permissions have been set properly? I mean you should try to get ACL of the created folder using command like :

```
(Get-Acl H:...).Access
```

Then check user's rights over this directory.

By the way, do you execute your script with elevated rights?

Comment: I have checked the permissions in the GUI and it looks right to me, the user, the admins and system got full control on the folder.
And the script is execuded as admin.

Comment: What about the parent folder (`C:\Homes`)? If I remember correctly, the users need to at least be able to list the contents of that folder.

Comment: I just got it to work, my share settings where not correct. Thank you all!